# Understanding the relation of flow through a nozzle to Mach number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

What happens to the flow in the convergent/divergent nozzle when the flow velocity in the convergent part is a) subsonic  b)Supersonic.                          Given equation:

dA/A= (M^2 -1)dV/V

I suppose when the flow is subsonic and Mach number is below 1, the velocity decreases as the area increases and vise versa.
In case of supersonic flow the velocity increases with the area.

Is this solution correct or something else is expected from the question?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. In a rocket engine (with sufficiently high chamber pressure) the flow is subsonic before the throat and speeds up as the nozzle narrows. The flow has $M=1$ exactly at the narrowest part.  After the throat the flow is supersonic and continues to  speed up as the nozzle widens.